# How to change the font color of strings-array

Tags: xml, string, android-layout, colors

I would like to change the font in strings-array
already tried the code below but no use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="my_data_list">

        <item><FONT color="#000000">Text1</FONT></item>
        <item><FONT color="#000000">Text2</FONT></item>
        <item><FONT color="#000000">Text3</FONT></item>
        <item><FONT color="#000000">Text4</FONT></item>

    </string-array>


</resources>
```

Comment: Where do you actually display that array? That's the code that we'll need to modify.

Comment: I show him in a class, I'm doing a ListView, follow an Arabic tutorial on Youtube and it worked just fine, but the font is white, and I would leave it black.

Comment: Look at the xml in your res/layout/ folder. There should be a small layout for the row of your listView. That's one of the locations where you can change the color of your font.

Comment: In xml not of the option to change the font color of the ListView.